# How to get location coordinates for a place using Google Places API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places

I am implementing `Google Places API`, using auto complete I do get place id, now by using place id I want to find the location coordinate for that place. `GMSPlace` doesn't return the geometry location. I searched but didn't get any help.

```
GMSPlacesClient *placeClient=[GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterEstablishment;

[placeClient autocompleteQuery:str
                        bounds:nil
                        filter:filter
                      callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                          if (error != nil) {
                              NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                              return;
                          }

                          for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                              //NSLog(@"Result '%@'", result.attributedFullText.string);
                              [placeName addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result.attributedFullText.string]];
                              [placeID addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result.placeID]];
                          }

                   NSLog(@"%@",placeName);
                   NSLog(@"%@",placeName);
   }];
}
```

Comment: shiw ur tried code

Comment: the code in comment @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @kishan check my answer its helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get place details by using place id like this

```
NSString *placeID = @"ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs";

[_placesClient lookUpPlaceID:placeID callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
  if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Place Details error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
  }

  if (place != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place placeID %@", place.placeID);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"No place details for %@", placeID);
  }
}];
```

reference : [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details)

Answer (score 1):

If you have place id you can find the coordinate by using this `URL`. This provide you the details of your place.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?input=bar&placeid=PLACE_ID&key=API_KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get place detail from place id. check this [Dock](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details). This call will return GMSPlace. GSMPlace have property coordinate.

Comment: yes, it shows in document but, coordinates are not returned.

Answer (score 1):

**MainDictionary** is `NSMutableDictionary`

```
plceidkey = @"YOUR_GOOGLE_MAP_PLACE_KEY"; 


NSString *URLString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=%@&key=%@", "YOUR_PLACE_ID",plceidkey];

NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                               URLWithString:URLString1]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1
                                                 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError *error;
MainDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// here you got address
address1=[[MainDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];

// here got your place name
placename=[[MainDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"name"];

// here got latitude of your place       
lat1=[[[[MainDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location" ]valueForKey:@"lat"];

// here got logitude of your place 
long1=[[[[MainDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location" ]valueForKey:@"lng"];
```

If any query about this code then inform me i just help you.

Happy Coding.